# Navigation Drawer App does not change fragments when clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Good Morning, I am a newbie programmer, and I use Navigation Drawer Android Studio Activity to start. Everything is ok when I compile, but when I use the app and click on the different options, nothing happens (I mean that the layout doesn't change and remain on the activity_main.xml). I look for other questions but (I think) no one has had my problem.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Ma giusto a provare", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container
                        , new CulturaClass()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container
                        , new CulturaClass()).commit();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

content_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_Cultura" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_organizer" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

fragment_cultura.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cultura generale!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="171dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="320dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VVVVai!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="403dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

CulturaClass.java

```java
public class CulturaClass extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cultura,container,false);
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="hello" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share some code ?

Comment: post the code of the clicks of the items of your navigation drawer.

Comment: Sure, I thought I did this. Sorry, I will modify the question

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Comment: in `onNavigationItemSelected()` method you replace the same fragments in both case.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not the problem, in fact never changes the home page. I mean, in CulturaClass I load fragment_cultura that has a Button and a TextView but I can't see Them

Comment: @satyan_android thank you but I would like to fix my error...

Comment: code edited added id to your FrameLayout.. as fragment_container..

Comment: where did you use content_main.xml file in your code

Comment: @KalpeshKulye I think... never...  At least in my Java Code... I am so confused............

Comment: I had posted a solution, checked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `R.id.fragment_container` provide name for `FrameLayout` in `activity_main.xml` and pass that name while replacing fragment i.e.

```
case R.id.nav_home:
     ft.replace(R.id.<name_of_framelayout>, new CulturaClass()).commit();
     break;

case R.id.nav_gallery:
     ft.replace(R.id.<name_of_framelayout>, new CulturaClass()).commit();
     break;
```

This might work for you

Answer (score 0):

> Because you are replacing fragment with same class:

```
case R.id.nav_home:
     ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container
            , new CulturaClass()).commit();    //Same Class  
     break;
case R.id.nav_gallery:
     ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container
           , new CulturaClass()).commit();    //Same Class
break;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is not the problem, in fact never changes the home page. I mean, in CulturaClass I load fragment_cultura that has a Button and a TextView but I can't see Them

Comment: No , you load same class again .

Comment: I changed the code as you sugggested, but nothing changes on the app

Comment: @Blogger I have added CulturaClass() code. Anyway nothing changes :(

Comment: Then change to another class!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing simple and easy way using common function or method and You never do mistake.

You have two option to use this One is using JAVA and second, is KOTLIN
The first Method I write below check this:

1. If you are using **java**, use like this method

First, create one function i.e name setFragment and pass the parameter Fragment class and second is a title (a Title is an optional if you use or not)
Declare the globally variable

```
private Fragment fragment = null;

//create function for replace fragment
private void setFragment(Fragment fragmentName, String title) {
    fragment = fragmentName;
    if (fragment != null) {
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment, fragment.getTag()).commit();
    }

    setTitle("Dashboard");

    // Close the navigation drawer
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

2. If you are using **KOTLIN**:

First, create one function i.e name openFragment and pass the parameter Fragment class and second is a title (a Title is an optional if you use or not)

Declare the globally variable

```
private var fragment: Fragment? = null

//create function for replace fragment
fun openFragment(fragmentClass: Fragment, titleName: String) {
    //pass the current fragment class name which you replace
    fragment = fragmentClass
    //check first fragment is null or not
    if (fragment != null) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment!!, fragment!!.tag).commit()
    }

    title = titleName // replace the titlename 
    //check the drawerLayout close or not
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
}
```